# paypal api upgrade to the latest version

Tags: paypal

I am working on upgrading the paypal API used in my application to the latest version from version 56.

From the documentation, it seems that AMT field has been deprecated and we have to use PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMAMT instead.Each payment in the transaction has a limit of 10 000.00 and only up to 10 payments are allowed.

Please help me with these questions

- Did the AMT field have any such limitation earlier for a transaction?
- In the new version, every transaction has a limit of 100 000?
- If the payment amount is in [lakhs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), how do we handle this case in the new version in a single transaction?